# Python script Permission Denied from shell script when invoked from Crontab

Tags: python, bash, shell, cron

I have to schedule some tasks for which I invoke a shell script in my home directory. I try to run a python script from this Shell script but it doesn't work.

I have tried the following till now.

1. I have validated that Crontab does invoke the shell script by echoing from the shell script to an output file
2. I ran the shell script independently from the terminal and it executes the python script successfully
3. I have added the shell script to chmod and also the python script

Shell script code

#!/bin/sh

python3 /absolute path/to/file/myfile.py >> log_script.txt

Comment: You should also capture errors by adding `2?&1` (note that it must be *after* the `>> log_script.txt`).

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks, I tried this, python3  /absolute path/to/file/myfile.py >> log_script.txt 2?&1, still nothing in the log file

Comment: Oops, sorry, that was a typo! It should've been `2>&1`.

Comment: yes, I tried with that, error I am getting is can't open file '/absolute path/to/file/myfile.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted. How can this be solved, I checked permission, its, -rwxr--r, it seems when crontab invokes this Shell script the permission is not allowed, else if I run the shell script from terminal it runs without error

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _but it doesn't work_?

Comment: @user1934428 the python script was not being executed

Comment: Silently skipped, without any error message??? I don't believe it.

Comment: BTW, why is this tagged _bash_? I don't see any bash involved, and you also don't show how you invoke your shell script.

Comment: Also, please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Code should always be formatted in fixed point fonts, because it is difficult to identify spaces properly when you use proportional font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this question thanks to get the good suggestion provided here https://www.bejarano.io/fixing-cron-jobs-in-mojave/, cron needs to be provided disk access, it seems, it doesn't have disk access by default, as a side not make sure to also allow terminal to have full disk access

Simply add the following to full disk access under,

System Settings > Privacy & Security > Full Disk Access

/usr/sbin/cron

Answer (score 1):

Try giving absolute path for the `log_script.txt`

`python3 /absolute path/to/file/myfile.py >> /absolute path/to/file/log_script.txt`

If you do not want to use the absolute path for `log_script.txt`. Just look for the file `log_script.txt` in cron working directory.
The cron working director (`pwd`) can be found using below method

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/what-is-the-working-directory-when-cron-executes-a-job

You have to check the `log_script.txt` in this directory

Comment: thanks, this worked to at least get the error logged: the error is,

Comment: can't open file '/absolute path/to/file/myfile.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted. How can this be solved

Comment: @Dspguysam what is the file permission for ```/absolute path/to/file/myfile.py```. can you try running the shell script using sudo privilege

Comment: output sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required

Comment: Can you get the file permission of the python file,  ```ls -l /absolute path/to/file/myfile.py```.

Comment: permission is -rwxr--r

Answer (score 0):

try to:
Check the environment variables and path.
Check the working directory.
Make sure the Python script has the correct line.
Check the execute permissions for both scripts.
Examine the log file for any errors or problems when running Cron.

Comment: working directory is ~/, execute permissions I have added to chmod for both files, the log_script.txt is strangely empty